# Detach a static const std::thread?

Tags: c++, static, constants, stdthread

Is this illegal? How do I hide this global thread instance with `private`? It seems to work without `const` but I would still like to const it just for peace of mind.

```
struct AbstractImage {
private:
    static void LoadImages();
    static const std::thread ImageLoader;
};
...
const std::thread AbstractImage::ImageLoader( AbstractImage::LoadImages );

void AbstractImage::LoadImages() {
    ImageLoader.detach();
}
```

```
'void std::thread::detach(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::thread' to 'std::thread &'
```

Comment: `detach` needs to mutate the state of the thread object. As you can see from the fact that is not a const method. So no you cannot detach on a const thread. "I would still like to const it just for peace of mind." What peace of mind? If you need detach you need it to be mutable.

Comment: I would be happy to not detach it, but otherwise it pops up a silly assert failed dialog at program exit.

Comment: Why do you need a global `std::thread` object at all?  Why not just call a function at startup, and have that function use a local `std::thread` that it detaches before exiting?

Comment: Re. `"...it pops up a silly assert failed dialog at program exit"`, that's because you're (probably) not [joining](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) it before its destructor is invoked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I use a private member so that it can call a private struct function

Comment: @G.M. right, but how to work around it?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko you don't need a `static std::thread` object for that. A local `std::thread` object inside a `static` method will work. If needed, you can make `std::thread` a `friend` of `AbstractImage`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And how do I invoke that static method? From main()? It's a thread that is supposed to call the method, not vice versa

Comment: @AntonDuzenko the method to start the thread can be called in the constructor of a global object (you don't need to make the `std::thread` itself global). Or, you can use `#pragma startup` or equivalent, if your compiler supports that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't have a dedicated instance of AbstractImage (and it's abstract BTW). Which is why the static thread. Not excited about pragma startup either.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko you don't need a dedicated instance of `AbstractImage`. I have written up an answer to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `detach()` on a `const std::thread` object, since `detach()` needs to modify the state of the `std::thread`.

In this case, I would suggest not using a static `std::thread` object at all.  Especially since it is a one-time-use thread, so the `std::thread` object doesn't need to hang around once the thread starts running.  Use a local `std::thread` variable inside of another function or static method, and then you can call that at startup as needed, eg:

```cpp
struct AbstractImage
{
private:
    static void LoadImages();

    struct LoadImagesStarter
    {
        LoadImagesStarter()
        {
            std::thread(AbstractImage::LoadImages).detach();
        }
    };

    static const LoadImagesStarter ImageLoader;
};
...

const AbstractImage::LoadImagesStarter AbstractImage::ImageLoader;

void AbstractImage::LoadImages()
{
    ...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/VtAleE)

Alternatively:

```cpp
struct AbstractImage
{
private:
    static void LoadImages();

    friend void LoadImagesStarter();
};
//...

void AbstractImage::LoadImages()
{
    ...
}

__attribute__((constructor)) void LoadImagesStarter()
{
    std::thread(AbstractImage::LoadImages).detach();
}

/* or, if your compiler supports this:
void LoadImagesStarter()
{
    std::thread(AbstractImage::LoadImages).detach();
}
#pragma startup LoadImagesStarter 100
*/
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rJ6ACM)